# .glusterfs folder takes 26 Terabytes (Gluster Volume)

Tags: rhel, glusterfs

I'm using Gluster on my cluster and I'm running into a problem with storage.

My data takes about 17 Terabytes out of the 36 Terabytes being used. So I looked around for what was taking the remaining 19 Terabytes and the only logical answer is `.glusterfs`. When I used the `du -hs` command on `.glusterfs`, it said that it was taking 24 Terabytes which doesn't make sense since 24+17 is 41 not 36. But I don't have anything else on the drives besides my Data and gluster.

I know `.glusterfs` is made up of hardlinks but is it possible that it's also generating files? I don't have the trashcan option enabled. Is there a way to find out what's taking the remaining 19 Terabytes and if it is gluster, is there anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have changelog feature enabled as part of Geo-replication? If yes then Changelogs files may have accumulated over time.

```
du -sh .glusterfs/changelogs
```